# Failed to Convert byte array into bitmap (Android)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bit

```
while(rs.next()){
String im = rs.getString("img_name");
byte[] image = im.getBytes();
Bitmap bitmapProfile = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmapProfile);
}
```

In the above code,
bitmapProfile returns null value

Comment: Are you intending to open a file and read the bytes, or is your image stored in a string in `rs`? As currently you're calling `getBytes()` on the string and not on a file.

Comment: Yes My image stored in a string as bytes. So that, I used getBytes()